# Angular Unit Test with puppeteer opens a command line window, breaks debugger

Tags: angular, puppeteer, karma-runner, karma-chrome-launcher

On an Angular project we use Puppeteer to include a Headless Chrome binary on dependency installation, it helps on a lot of things, including CI. The way to do this is described [Here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#headless-chromium-with-puppeteer)

It always worked fine but since last Chromium binary version bump (done with Puppeteer v19.7.0), when executing `npm test` it opens a command line window, which also breaks Karma debugger attachment on Webstorm IDE. The last puppeteer version on which we didn't have any issue was 19.6.3

I didn't find any breaking changes with the new Chromium version and had no issue launching it in Headless mode. (it can be found in npm `.cache` folder)

I tried changing the `karma-chrome-launcher` configuration, defining a custom Chrome launcher with `--headless` and other flags.

I tried different puppeteer versions, only versions before 19.7.0 worked.

I cleared npm cache and retry from scratch, event deleted chrome binaries.

To reproduce the issue I created a new empty Angular Project, which I updated to synchronise deps versions and Add a Karma configuration file to include Puppeteer Chrome.

Here's the files :

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "angular-karma-puppeteer-issue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test --no-watch"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.1",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "tslib": "2.5.0",
    "zone.js": "0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "4.5.0",
    "karma": "6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "19.7.5",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

### karma.conf.js

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/angular-karma-puppeteer-issue'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```